# Como podria hacer para que al pedir los datos de direccion, me pregunte por los 3 atributos de dicha clase y no me lo ponga como una String

Tags: java, poo

```
package Biblioteca;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    ArrayList <Cliente> ListaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    ArrayList <Direccion> ListaDireccion = new ArrayList<Direccion>();
    ArrayList <Libros> ListaLibros = new ArrayList <Libros>();


    int limite=0;

    while(limite == 0){

        System.out.println("Menu Biblioteca"+"/n"+"1-Nuevo Cliente"+"/n"+"2-Modificar Cliente"+"/n"+"3-Buscar cliente"+"/n"+"4-Mostrar Clientes"+"/n"+"5-Salir");

        int op = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());

        switch (op){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Ingrese los siguientes datos:"+"/n");

                System.out.println("Ingresar Nombre:"+"/n");
                String nombre = bf.readLine();

                System.out.println("Ingresar Direccion:"+"/n");
                Direccion direccion = bf.readLine();

                System.out.println("Ingresar Telefono:"+"/n");
                String Telefono = bf.readLine();

                System.out.println("Ingresar Correo:"+"/n");
                String correo = bf.readLine();

                System.out.println("Ingresar Nuevo ID:"+"/n");
                int IDusuario = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());

                System.out.println("Ingresar Multas:"+"/n");
                Multa multa = bf.readLine();

                Cliente c1 = new Cliente(nombre,direccion,Telefono,correo,IDusuario,multa);
                Direccion d1= new Direccion (Calle,Colonia,CP);
                ListaClientes.add(c1);
                ListaDireccion.add(d1);

            break;
            case 2:
            break;
            case 3:
            break;
            case 4:
            break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("El programa finalizo");
                limite = 99;
            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Hola. Deberías editar la pregunta, acortar el título y detallar que necesitas. Entendí que tu clase *Direccion* tiene 3 propiedades, por ejemplo ¿ *cp*, *calle* y *número*? y necesitas cada dato a partir de la lectura de la dirección introducida en tu programa actual? No se puede, deberías solicitar cada dato por separado. Si sólo tienes un string con "todo" dentro tendrías que indicar el formato de la respuesta y luego controlar que la entrada cumpla ese formato, y te pueden poner cualquier cosa, por eso hay formularios con múltiples campos, se trata de acotar cada tipo de dato concreto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un JDialog, JOptionPane,JEditorPane... con diferentes inputs:
Aqui tienes ejemplos completos y explica como utilizarlos:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Saludos.

Comment: ¿? Todo eso es para GUI, y el programa del OP es por línea de comando.